# What does the statement "int? i1 = i2" do in c#?

Tags: c#

I have been reading a c# tutorial and it has mentioned about nullable types and in that particular context I have gone through this example

```
int? i1 = i2;
```

I was unable to understand what does it exactly do and what it mean.

Comment: what is the definition of i2?

Comment: What, specifically, is confusing you about this line of code?  Do you know what it means to declare a variable, do you know what it means to initialize a variable when declaring it?  Do you not understand what the type is?  Do you not understand what a semicolon is there for, or what?  When you just provide some code and say "explain" without specifying what you don't understand, the question isn't really answerable.

Answer (score 5):

It means, declare a nullable `int` type and assign it the value of `i2`.

Because `i1` has nullable type `int?`, `i2` can be an `int` literal like `5`, a variable of type `int`, a variable of type `int?` or the literal value `null`.

Answer (score 3):

It creates a **nullable** integer. Meaning you can set `i1 = null;` and easily test for its nullity `i1.HasValue`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Answer (score 2):

`int? i1` means that `i1` variable can be `null` means **nullable variable** and you are assigning `i2` to it whatever the value is in `i2`.

**For Example:**

if i have a method like:

```
public int sum(int? num)
{
return 1;
}
```

`int?` means that `num` is can be passed as `null` instead of valid `integer`.

See [Nullable Types in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

Comment: It is mandatory, it just allows one more value (null) to be passed. Optional would look like `int? num = 1`

Comment: by optional i mean null can be passed

Comment: i edited it to make no confusion

Answer (score 1):

It is semantically the same as

```
Nullable<int> i1 = i2
```